# SQL Join Within Same Table based on matching values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 database with three columns: `dt`, `indx_nm`, and `indx_val`

When I run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.indx_nm = 'ABQI' OR a.indx_nm = 'ACNACTR'
ORDER BY indx_nm, dt
```

I get something like (just select random 8 of the 3000 values)

```
    # dt--------------indx_nm----------------indx_val
    2009-06-08---------ABQI------------------1001.25
    2009-06-09---------ABQI------------------1002.12
    2010-06-08---------ABQI------------------928.76
    2011-06-10---------ABQI------------------959.97
    2009-06-08--------ACNACTR----------------300.05
    2009-06-09--------ACNACTR----------------341.19
    2010-04-08--------ACNACTR----------------428.26
    2011-07-10--------ACNACTR----------------509.48
```

Is there some way I could return a result that looks like

```
    # dt---------indx_nm1-----indx_val1-------indx_nm2------indx_val2
    2009-06-08----ABQI------1001.2------------ACNACTR----------300.05
    2009-06-09----ABQI------1002.12 ----------ACNACTR----------341.19
```

Essentially matching the shared dates between index numbers and then joining the other `indx_nm` and its corresponding `indx_val` to the result?

## *addendum

so im trying to find the covariance between `ABQI` and `ACNACTR`. I know that I could take the average of the entire `indx_val1`' and average of the entire `index_val2` but is there a way I could loop through the entire set of 1000+ rows to for each value of `indx_val1` and `indx_val2` to input in (xi-x)(yi-y) / n

 i could probably does this on vba more easily but i dont think it would be able to handle it (i have hundreds of indx_nm that i would like to determine the covariance of)

Comment: To format a code block, highilght it and `ctl-k` or click the editor's `{}` button, or indent 4 spaces. No need for `<br>` tags.

Comment: Are there going to be an indeterminate set of values like `ABQI,ACNACTR`, or is it always a specific known set you'll be querying for?

Comment: itd be a specific known set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you may `GROUP BY dt`, and with a combination of the aggregate `MAX()` and `CASE`, return the correct columns while collapsing multiple rows with NULLs into a single row.

```
SELECT 
  dt,
  MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ABQI' THEN indx_nm ELSE NULL END) AS indx_nm1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ABQI' THEN indx_val ELSE NULL END) AS indx_val1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ACNACTR' THEN indx_nm ELSE NULL END) AS indx_nm2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ACNACTR' THEN indx_val ELSE NULL END) AS indx_val2
FROM table1 a
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ec65/1

Without the `MAX()` aggregates, you would end up with two rows for each value of `dt` where either the `ABQI` or the `ANACTR` pair are `NULL`. The `MAX()` aggregate then selects the "greatest" of the null and non-null value, resulting in one grouped row per `dt`.

Now, if you wanted to return *only* those values for `dt` which have *both* of the `indx_nm` populated (no `NULL`s), you may just wrap the above in a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
      dt,
      MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ABQI' THEN indx_nm ELSE NULL END) AS indx_nm1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ABQI' THEN indx_val ELSE NULL END) AS indx_val1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ACNACTR' THEN indx_nm ELSE NULL END) AS indx_nm2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ACNACTR' THEN indx_val ELSE NULL END) AS indx_val2
    FROM table1 a
    GROUP BY dt
) indxs
WHERE
  /* Discard those rows where either pair is NULL */
  indx_nm1 IS NOT NULL
  AND indx_nm2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dt
```

**Edit** Whoops, that errant `WHERE` clause should not have been there.

Comment: @euge1220 Have you tested the query at the bottom? That's what it does. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ec65/8

Comment: o im trying to find the covariance between ABQI and ACNACTR. I know that I could take the average of the entire indx_val1' and average of the entire index_val2 but is there a way I could loop through the entire set of 1000+ rows to for each value of indx_val1 and indx_val2 to input in (xi-x)(yi-y) / n 
i could probably does this on vba more easily but i dont think it would be able to handle it (i have hundreds of indx_nm that i would like to determine the covariance of)

Comment: @euge1220 What is `i` in `xi, yi` (I am not that familiar with statistics)? This drastically changes your original question.

Comment: It would be (indx_val2 - avg(indx_val2))*((indx_val1) - avg(indx_val1)) divided by total number of rows looped through each value of indx_val1 and indx_val2 for each date.. yeah i know haha sorry about that